# How can I exclude punctuation from this regex while including accented letters?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm trying to fix some code in Laravel that matches keywords to their occurrences in a text. Because it's foreign-language words and text, I'm running into some problems - I'm able to tell it that, say, "stackoverflow!" should match to "stackoverflow" with this line:

```
$test = str_replace(array(',','.','!',';',':','?'), '', trim(strtolower($word)));
```

but I don't know how to encode it such that it 1. doesn't break on guillemets and inverted punctuation, while 2. successfully handling accented characters. I wrote a line which was intended to just exclude anything that wasn't a letter from being considered in matching:

```
$test = preg_replace("/[^\x41-\x7A\xC0-\xFF]/","", $test);
```

but this is the worst of both worlds - it fails on the guillemets, while also failing to make sure that keywords with accents get matched despite those being in the identified character range.

Needless to say, I did try writing regex to identify the characters themselves, their HTML names...and more.

If the problem is just that there's failure to recognize the extended character table, how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace('~[\p{P}\p{S}]+~u', '', trim(strtolower($word)))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just gave it a try and unfortunately this prevents *any* keyword from being successfully identified.

Comment: You say you want to remove punctuation, it does that.

Comment: I just took another look at it and it seems that it does not remove inverted punctuation or angle quotes, but it *does* remove accented letters. I was mistaken before in saying that it's a step backwards and prevents any keyword from being identified, but it doesn't solve my problem, which is how to remove special punctuation while leaving accented letters in place.

Comment: `preg_replace('~[\p{P}\p{S}]+~u', '', trim(strtolower($word)))` cant remove letters as `~[\p{P}\p{S}]+~u` only matches punctuation and symbols. Check the other code.

Comment: I put it in the place in the code where it would go, and it did not remove punctuation or angle quotes, but it did remove accented letters. Is there something else I should be looking for elsewhere in the code that could be affecting how this functions? I assure you that I dropped your code directly in and it did not work.

Comment: Please share the exact code snippet reproducing the behavior. I cant believe what you say as it is impossible.

Comment: Okay, give me a sec - it's too long to post here but I don't have enough reputation to move this to chat

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/048433806b715a0278b22f641b3548f2682ec0a2

Comment: Looks like there is a syntax error  in your code.

Comment: Any clues as to what that might be?

Answer (score -2):

I have Created the function to remove all the special charaters for the string

```
     /**
     * Removes the Special Charater from the string
     *
     * @author Manojkiran.A <manojkiran10031998@gmail.com>
     * @param string $stringWiSpCh The Strings With Special Charateers
     * @return string
     **/
    function removeSpecial(string $stringWiSpCh)
    {
        // Removes special chars.
        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $stringWiSpCh);
    }
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: No thank you, as I mentioned, I'd already written a function that removes everything that isn't a letter, but the problem is that it doesn't think an accented letter is a letter.